# Index page display performance poor using datatable/will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql, datatables, will-paginate

Environment: Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Windows 8.1, PostreSQL, Datatable 1.12.2, Will_Paginate 3.0.5, all on a development high-end laptop running both server and client.  Note, the original question was deleted and replaced with this question to directly address the cause of the issue.

I’m having performance issues with the index action of my app when I seed the database to simulate a full load.  The problem seems to be that it reads the entire model database and then it reads the records that it needs to display the index.

The controller code is causing this issue.  It differs from Railscast 340 in this case.  I added the line that causes problems because I was getting errors without it.  Obviously, this patch is wrong.  The controller code actually issues the read of the recordset before the respond_to.  This is not shown in Railscast 340, but is shown in the [respond_to documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to).  Without it, I receive an error in the view.  The controller code is:

```
  def index
    @products = Product.all   # This line seems to be the problem, but errors occur without it.
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: ProductsDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
  end
```

The view segment that receives the nomethoderror for each on nil, when the @products = Product.all is not in the controller index action, is:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
```

On sample run, shown below, it takes about 3.4 seconds for the first sequence and 0.1 second for the second sequence.  This sample is only on my development system, which is a high-end laptop running both server and client.  But, I am very concerned that this design won’t scale even when distributed into production.

The first read and completion is:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."company_id" = 54
…
Completed 200 OK in 3393ms (Views: 2851.6ms | ActiveRecord: 418.3ms)
```

The following read and completion is:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."company_id" = 54 ORDER BY stock_number asc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
…
Completed 200 OK in 103ms (Views: 71.0ms | ActiveRecord: 26.0ms)
```

EDIT to add Explain Analyze

Interesting difference in that the first query shows no index, but the schema says products is indexed by company?

First query:

```
"Seq Scan on products  (cost=0.00..12.65 rows=234 width=51) (actual time=0.036..0.114 rows=234 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (company_id = 54)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 218"
"Total runtime: 0.153 ms"
```

Second query:

```
"Limit  (cost=0.27..6.76 rows=10 width=51) (actual time=0.015..0.036 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using index_products_on_stock_number on products  (cost=0.27..152.07 rows=234 width=51) (actual time=0.014..0.033 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (company_id = 54)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 14"
"Total runtime: 0.063 ms"
```

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE for these two queries?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add pagination `Product.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)`

Comment: @FrankHeikens.  I'd be glad to, but I get a nomethoderror trying to run explain.  The AR Query Guide says, "You can run EXPLAIN on the queries triggered by relations."  This is a direct query, not a relation.  Would that be why it fails?  Can you tell me how to run it in this case?  Thanks...

Comment: @edaried.  Railscast 340 leaves pagination to the ProductsDatatable class.  I'm attempting to limit the records I am passing using a .first(50) query, for example.  The first view shows only 50 records but subsequent views are corrected.  It's not an optimum solution.  Ideas?  Thanks...

Comment: You can use psql, pgAdmin or whatever PostgreSQL-client you like, to run your queries on your database: EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT _rest_of_your_sql;

Comment: @R_G I looked at Railscast 340 and it looks like you forget to remove `@products.each do |product|` from your views. DataTable uses data only from server JSON response not from rendered views.

Comment: @edaried I totally did not see that, and I have read and viewed the cast many times...  I'll look it over.  If that is accurate, that would seem to be the problem.

Comment: @FrankHeikens  The information has been added to the question at the end.  Thanks.

Comment: @FrankHeikens There is no need to use `EXPLAIN` it only shows, that he tries to fetch a lot of records from the database in the first read and in the second he tries to fetch only 10 of them. It perfectly explains the differences between those runtimes.

Comment: Your database is fine, results are found very fast. You could use an index on company_id, but that's (in your current situation) a minor issue. I can't help you with Rails, unknown territory for me :-(

Comment: @edariedl : Fetching a few records takes seconds? Hard to believe this is normal behavior. "rows=234"

Comment: @edariedl Okay, I totally missed that change in the cast!  Too funny.  Please post the answer so that I can accept it.  And, thanks to all of you for your attention and responses.  You all make this forum very valuable!

Comment: If you look at code on http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables to file `views/products/index.html.erb`, you will see, that he removed body of `tbody` in the table. Your problem is, that on the first loading of page you tries to load and include all records from your database into view.

Comment: @edaried and all, the table in question has many associations and some are complex.  There are at least 6 or more additional reads for every record pulled.  That's one reason why it was so critical just to pull the records that I absolutely needed.

Comment: @edaried, I meant to post it as an answer, not a comment, so that I can accept it and close the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @FrankHeikens no it should not, I am little bit confused about it. I thought that there was a lot more rows than 234 in the database.

Comment: @R_G yes I know sorry, I saw your comment after I posted it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at code on railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables to file `views/products/index.html.erb`, you will see, that he removed body of tbody in the table. Your problem is, that on the first loading of page you tries to load and include all records from your database into view.